# Getting Null response instead of json in jquery post from aspx.cs page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I am working on simple application where i am hitting the **Request.aspx** page from **default2.aspx** using jquery ajax post method as you can see below:

**js page:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#login").click(function () {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Request.aspx?Login=True",
        data: "{'username': '" + email + "','password': '" + password + "'}",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var url = "http://google.com";
            //$(location).attr('href', url);
        }
    });
});
```

});

**Default.aspx:**

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="Scripts/LoginCode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main" id="loginform">
            <label>
                Email :</label>
            <input type="text" name="demail" id="email" />
            <label>
                Password :</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            <input type="button" name="login" id="login" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

**Request.cs Page:**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Request.QueryString["Login"] != null)
    {

            test();

    };

}



private string test()
{
    var response = new ResponseResult();
    var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    response.Status = -1;
    response.ErrorMessage = "";
    response.Action = "UserProjects";
    response.Data = "The Username or password you entered is not valid";
   return javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(response);
}

public class ResponseResult
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem:**
In response NUll is coming but i am expected json. Please let me know where i am going wrong.

If you need more info i will try my best to provide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You return JSON in test but it's never used and you don't echo it.

Comment: yes as jcubic mentioned you are not making use of the json returned from your test method.

Comment: @jcubic how i can return it from page_load method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good idea to use Restful Webservices or Web Method to call from AJAX.

But still you can do the following.

Use `Response.Write()` instead of returning string.

Use this code.

```
private void test()

{
    var response = new ResponseResult();
    var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    response.Status = -1;
    response.ErrorMessage = "";
    response.Action = "UserProjects";
    response.Data = "The Username or password you entered is not valid";
    string result = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(response);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Response.Write(result);  //write json string to output   
}
```